# How do I determine the number of lines of text that will fit into a browser window

Tags: javascript

I want to display enough lines of text to fill the current size of the browser window. 
Also, I'd like to update the value if the browser window changes size. Does javascript have the equivalent of SIGWINCH?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with SIGWINCH, so I can't say there is no equivalent. What I do know is that you can't simply have javascript return the amount of text lines left on a page. This is simply because every font has (/ can have) a different height. What you need to do is 1) fetch a user's window height, 2) generate a span or div with a piece of text in it (the whole character set would be most conclusive, if you have enough width), 3) fetch the height of that div/ span to determine the height of the font 4) remove the sample span/ div 5) divide and floor the window height by the font height. And when the user changes the window's dimension, do the whole procedure again (window size changes can be noticed through the window.onresize even listener). You can of course save yourself some time by storing the font height after you have determined it the first time, though depending on how you write your function, that shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Once you figure out the height of each line (will depend on your css) you can do something like this (using jquery):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var text = '',
            i = 0, 
            lineHeight = 12, // replace with correct value
            numLines = Math.floor($(this).height() / lineHeight);

        for(i; i < numLines; i++) {
            text += "text <br />";
        }

        $('body').html(text);
    });
    window.resize();
});
```

Comment: yes, I forgot that you need to check the line height, not the font height. And since this is indeed a value one sets through CSS, there is no need to hassle with the line of test-text.

Comment: Needs to account for wrapping lines and the padding, borders and margin of containing block elements.

Comment: @robg: true, but hard to account for without more information from op.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy element, measure its height in pixels, then destroy it.

The number of lines you need is `viewport height`/`height of line`.

The equivalent of SIGWINCH in the browser is a resize event; you can set the handler as `window.onresize = function(event){...};` (or use jQuery to set the `'resize'` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is keep adding text (say by word, scentence, paragraph) until scroll bars appear, then go back to the last compelete word, sentence, paragraph, whatever.

A lightly tested *hasScrollBars* function is:

```
function hasScrollBars(el) {
  var s = el.style;
  var borderW = parseInt(s.borderLeftWidth,10) +
                parseInt(s.borderRightWidth,10);
  var borderH = parseInt(s.borderTopWidth,10) + 
                parseInt(s.borderBottomWidth,10);

  return el.offsetHeight > el.clientHeight + borderH || 
         el.offsetWidth > el.clientWidth + borderW;
}
```